# Git: I have a repo that has tens of thousands of files in it. I want to clean this up, and put everything into a zip, and use LFS. How?

Tags: git

So as the title says, I have a git repo that currently has tens of thousands of files in it.  There is no reason why these files cant be in an a few archives.  This repo is only downloaded once per developer, and `git pulls` are not necessary.

Is there a way to remove those thousands of files without having git track all those deletions? I basically want to wipe the repo and start over.  Should I just delete it?

Comment: Create a new repo looking exactly like you need it to be, and migrate to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care at all about the history of the repo you can simply overwrite everything like this:

```
rm -Rf lots/of/files
rm -Rf .git # remove git history
git init # start new repo
git add .
git commit -m 'initial'
git remote add origin yourURL
git push --force origin master # force push
```

Now, the users of that repo can take in it's changes like this:

```
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master
git gc # remove old detached history
```

Comment: So I guess I just learned that the history of the git repo is stored in the `.git`.  Is that right?  So if I blow away the `.git` and make a new one with `init` then all that history is gone if I commit the new one?

Comment: @R4F6 correct...the git history is all stored in `.git` so making a repo a non-repo can be accomplished by simply deleting `.git`.

Comment: Everything git has cloned is put in .git.  What is suggested is essentially forgetting everything and creating a brand new repository.  This also demonstrates why `--force` is very dangerous.